# how to create rounded corner for mobile web view

Tags: mobile, opera-mini

Is it possible to create rounded corner that viewable on opera mini (version 4) ?

friend of mine asking whether i could create a mobile view site that has rounded corner on their design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create round corners in Opera Mini with the same tricks that had to be used before browsers started supporting the border-radius CSS property. Opera Mini currently uses [Opera Presto 2.4](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto24/) which generally supports border-radius (eg in Opera Desktop 10.5), but it is not supported by Mini.

Comment: Please post link to what you are describing

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 supports this, there is also a special ["-moz-border-radius"](http://smhill.net/resources/css/rounded_corners/) style atttribute which FF (maybe Opera) supports. Nevertheless non of them is for all browsers. One solution is to create small rounded corner images as backgrounds for panels. Take a look how GMail is doing it.